# Changing the status of a temporary file with the open statement in gfortran

Tags: fortran, status, gfortran

I am using an old Fortran code and I have running it using g77-3.3 in an old OS. Since this version of the compiler no longer comes with most Linux distributions I tried using gfortran (4.9.2), and I am facing this small problem.

This codes uses temporary files. It writes to this file and then at a certain point it changes the status of the file to scratch, like in the following example:

```
      PROGRAM testopenfile
      IMPLICIT NONE
      WRITE(8,*)'fdsasfd'
      OPEN(8,STATUS='SCRATCH')
      CLOSE(8)
      END PROGRAM
```

This piece of code works with the g77 compiler, but when I run it with gfortran I get the message:

```
  At line 4 of file testopenfile.f (unit = 8, file = 'fort.8')
  Fortran runtime error: Cannot change STATUS paramter in OPEN statement.
```

Has this way of setting temporary files changed in gfortran? Am I doing something wrong? Could this be a bug in this version of gfortran?

Comment: I've changed the indentation of your code as I guess you meant it to be in fixed-form (g77 and it was in column 7 in the raw code).  If this isn't what you intended, feel free to change it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write to unit `8` **before** opening the file, you are in fact writing to a file called `fort.8`, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19422-01/819-3685/2_io.html). Apparently, this file is still open at unit `8` when you try to attach the scratch file to it.

You can solve this by opening the scratch file before writing to the unit:

```
      PROGRAM testopenfile
      IMPLICIT NONE
      OPEN(8,STATUS='SCRATCH')
      WRITE(8,*)'fdsasfd'
      CLOSE(8)
      END PROGRAM
```

or by using a different unit.

Chapter C.6.3 ("OPEN statement (9.5.6)") in the [Fortran 2008 Standard](http://www.j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf) treats this case and has an example which looks just like your code. It states that this *"example is invalid because it attempts to change the value of the `STATUS=` specifier."*

Comment: The problem is that the code writes in this file long before reaching this OPEN statement.In the first link you provide, in 2.1.2.2. Already Open, it says: _iIf the file has already been opened by the program, you can use a subsequent OPEN statement to change some of the file's characteristics; for example, BLANK and FORM. Does it apply to the STATUS option? And do you know if g77 is doing something wrong by not showing this error?

Comment: Yes, but you cannot change the `STATUS` specifier, see the second link, chapter  C.6.3.

Comment: I'm not sure what `g77` is doing, but it is not according to the Standard. BTW: `ifort` warns about the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the file on closing, you can also do

```
      PROGRAM testopenfile
      IMPLICIT NONE
      WRITE(8,*)'fdsasfd'
      CLOSE(8,status='DELETE')
      END PROGRAM
```